# Passing multiple string as parameter through url in laravel to delete specific data from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to delete multiple string data that is passed by url separated by  ','.

Scenario is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/remove/lui,kui
```

Through this route lui and kui data that is value of name field in database will be deleted.

My `web.php` file

```
Route::get("/remove/{name}",[MyController::class,"remove"]);
```

`MyController.php` file

```
use App\Models\City;   
function remove($name){

}
```

Thanks,your suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can accomplish this with the following:**

```
//The string of names
$names = "cat,cat,cat,mouse,dog,rabbit";

//We break it down, seperate them by comma, then add them to an array
//After we will get the unique values only of that array
$arrayOfNames = array_unique(explode(',', $names));
    
//search in the name column for any of these values
//delete if found
//note that you can change the word "name" to any other column name
City::whereIn('name', $arrayOfNames)->delete();
```

If you have the softdelete trait in your model, and would like to hard delete its: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

```
//search in the name column for any of these values
//hard delete if found
City::whereIn('name', $arrayOfNames)->forceDelete();
```

You can also do an update as well if that is something you are interested in the future:

```
//search in the name column for any of these values
//update if found
City::whereIn('name', $arrayOfNames)->update(['age' => 123, 'updated_at' => now()]);
```

Hope it works well for you :)